# Windows Task scheduler cannot run after server rebooting

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

I'm using Windows server 2016 datacenter. My scheduled tasks in Task Scheduler always stop running whenever server is rebooted. It starts to work again only after I manually go in the app and retype in my user account password. Is this a setting or conditions issue?

Answer (score 0):

Windows tasks are arranged per user. So, as long as that particular user did not log in, there is no need for launching those tasks.

I'd advise you to check which user is logged at reboot: the tasks, corresponding to that user, should be launched.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Sry I didn't make this clear enough. I'm a user (not Admin), it's me setting up these scheduled tasks. Our server is (and always) rebooted by the Admin. He said the user account I'm using has administrative privileges. I found that I need to relaunch my tasks always after the Admin rebooted our server on his end. I'm sure the Admin is logged at reboot. Still confusing to me...

Comment: Please check the "general" tab: there's the "security options" part. How is this filled in?